# CodeIgniter Route works over CIFS mount but not with local files

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, routes, mount

our dev environment at work uses a single centos machine with apache/php that serves different virtual hosts for both CIFS mounted and local directories. our application is built using CodeIgniter 2.0

we recently made a change to our Routes that is working fine for the virtual hosts serving the mounted drives, but the routes cannot be resolved for local files, resulting in a 404.

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://production.host.com"; // the production value of $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] essentially
```

routes:

```
$route['companyone'] = 'sso/platformsso/requestgenericsso/companyone';
$route['companyone/(:any)'] = 'sso/ptlatformsso/requestgenericsso/companyone/$1';
```

this works for the following scenario:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:80>
    ServerAdmin me@host.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/mnt/a"
    ServerName "a.tmbc.com"
    ErrorLog logs/a.error.log
    Alias ssaml /var/simplesamlphp/www
</VirtualHost>
<Directory "/var/mnt/a">
    Options  FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Directory populated using CIFS mount: mount -t cifs //1.2.3.4/a /var/mnt/a -o rw,username=un,password=pwd,uid=48 --verbose1
```

but does not work for this scenario:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:80>
    ServerAdmin me@host.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/b"
    ServerName "b.host.com"
    ErrorLog logs/b.error.log
    Alias ssaml /var/simplesamlphp/www
</VirtualHost>
<Directory "/var/www/html/b">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Directory populated using SVN checkout: svn checkout file:///var/svn/repo/trunk /var/www/html/b
```

.htaccess:

```
AddType text/x-component .htc

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Restrict unused HTTP methods
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST|HEAD)
    RewriteRule .* - [R=405,L]

    # Forces SSL
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^_sys.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^_app.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*).(pdf|exe|doc|mp4)$ /externaldownload/?fileLocation=$1.$2 [R,L]
    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

any ideas of why this is so?

Comment: Can you share your vhosts file and your `$config['base_url']`  setting?

Comment: added that info. thx for the help @PoX

Comment: I think you having rewritemod/htaccess related issues check those or share them here, we might be able to help. Based on server name I assume its that

Comment: added `.htaccess`. we've been using this setup for a few years now. the biggest change is the sso route value. the route lines, now 2, used to be one line: `$route['companyone'] = 'sso/companyone/requestSSO';`

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your issue here. Problem seems to be on `(:any)` your route rule.

```
$route['companyone/(:any)'] = 'sso/ptlatformsso/requestgenericsso/companyone/$1';
```

A URL with `companyone` as the first segment of URL and anything for the second segment will be remapped to `sso/ptlatformsso/requestgenericsso/companyone/$1`

It seems like codeigniter passing `$1` as a variable to the function `companyone` which means you are actually matching any route there to forced to rewrite.

How about condensing those to route rules and make a

```
$route['(.*)'] = "sso/ptlatformsso/requestgenericsso/companyone/$1";
```

or have only one rule there for routes such as

```
$route['companyone/(:any)'] = 'sso/ptlatformsso/requestgenericsso/companyone/$1';
```